# Opennms: How to increase the events listing in the events page

Tags: opennms

I'm hoping someone can shed the some light on this.

If you are familiar with Opennms then you know that the events page will only display a maximum of 10 records at a time.

Is there a away to change this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could either use the "Advanced Event Search" or you could manually change the "limit" attribute.

Advanced Event Search : `http://localhost:8980/opennms/event/advsearch.jsp`

Manually Change the Limit Attribute: `http://localhost:8980/opennms/event/list?limit=1000`

Comment: Thanks. I didnt notice those limit options in the link until you click on the next page.